# Can communication satellites be used in lunar orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, communication-satellite

Because the moon always has the same [orientation to earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking), if we want to have communications with manned or robotic explorers on the far side some type of relay would be needed for communication.  Would a communication satellites used in lunar orbit be possible or would the tidal effects of earth disrupt the orbit to make it impossible/impractical?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not really about tidal effects of the Earth but about irregularities of [lunar gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit#Perturbation_effects) ([Mascons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_%28astronomy%29)) necessitating large fuel expenditures for maintaining an orbit around the Moon.

[image: GRAIL gravity anomaly map]

Taken from: http://boingboing.net/2013/06/23/lunar-gravity-maps.html

The solution (first proposed in 1966 by R. Farquhar) is to place a comms relay into a [halo orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_orbit) around the Earth-Moon L2 [Lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point).

In 1973 Farquhar and Kamel found a "natural" halo orbit providing almost constant coverage (in-plane oscillation should be greater than 32379 kilometers):

[image]

References:

- Farquhar, R. W. The Control and Use of Libration-Point Satellites. Ph.D. Dissertation, Dept. of Aeronautics and Astronautics, Stanford University, Stanford, CA, 1968.
- J.Masdemont. Libration Point Orbits and Applications. 2003. P.47.