# If the ISS went to the moon, what would fail first

Tags: iss, the-moon, spacecraft, design-alternative

If the ISS was propelled into an orbit (any orbit) around the moon, what would fail first?

Comment: Duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29543/6944 but it does not have an answer.

Comment: "What would fail first" isn't exactly the same as "what would be needed", but I take your point :)

Comment: The first thing to falter and fail would be the political will to finance that endeavor.

Comment: I’m assuming it was a hijack :)

Comment: Well, the communication systems wouldn't *fail* per se, but they wouldn't work, as they're designed to talk to TDRSS, which is not really easily done from the moon.

Comment: @Tristan there's always the VHF voice channel via Ham radio: "Earth! Send help! We've been [kidnapped](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48596/if-the-iss-went-to-the-moon-what-would-fail-first#comment157172_48596) in space and are being held in lunar orbit!" thought I am not sure the messages would end up getting forwarded to NASA :-)